# memory allocation for "yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb" greater than the physical memory size

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

What happens when we allocate the memory size greater than physical memory as follows,

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
   <value>20960</value>
</property
```

In My case am having **12 GB memory** and 2 core cpu! By adding the memory greater(**20GB**) than physical memory it will create more containers than default memory value as per the physical memory. Is it shares the Secondary memory ? how it shares?

Comment: Read about page sharing; all "modern" OSes use that

Comment: 1. Allocated containers doesn't have to necessarily consume all the reserved memory. So they may fit into the memory, depends on the JVM heap usage.  
2.  If they do not fit into memory, some containers won't be started.

Comment: hi vanekjar,
thank yu for the comment, In my case am having oly 12 GB RAM but i reserved 20 GB for the nodemanager, Once the job submitted it utilize the memory which is greater than 12 GB ie greater then the RAM size.!! Is it share any virtual memory ?

Comment: How are you measuring if the are using more than 12 Gb ram? And what about jvm heap size?

Comment: @PedroMagalhaes in hadoop metrics will show the total memory usage in the WEBUI . by there we have exceeding the Ram size.